# MySQL query for multiple join in multiple table

Tags: mysql, database, join, select

So I have 3 tables that I wanna join to get the data. That I want. Here are the tables and the output that I want. Please help me., Thanks!

tournament_table

| id | tournament_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Summer League Tournament |
| 2 | Seasonal Tournament |

tournament_participant table

| p_id | tournament_id | team_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |

team_name table

| team_id | team_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha |
| 2 | Bravo |
| 3 | Charlie |

And heres the output the I want

output if tournament id = 1

| t_name | # of teams | team_names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Summer League Tournament | 2 | Alpha, Bravo |

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow Lance! its kind of hard to digest your question, could you edit it a bit to be more readable? also, have you tried any solution you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and then some [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) to get the relevant data.

```
select
   t.tournament_name as t_name,
   count(distinct tn.team_id) as '# of teams',
   group_concat(tn.team_name) as team_names
  from tournament_table as t
  left join tournament_participant as tp
    on t.id = tp.tournament_id
  left join team_name as tn
    on tp.team_id = tn.team_id
where t.id = 1
group by t.id;
```

The involved aggregate functions are:

- [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count) to count the participants. The `distinct` modifier used to count each participant only once.
- [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate string value inside the columns

The query assumes `tournament_name.id` is a primary key, otherwise you have to resort to [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value).

See Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7iT6NGXioX3qk5YoaudE1t/2

Comment: @user1191247 you are right the best kind of correct, but i'm not sure if op put the proper keys and i didn't bother adding them in the fiddle, my bad.

Comment: wow thats fast. thanks for your help mate! appreciate it!!!